# Convert the factor to numeric in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data and i use read.table(...) in to r. and let w<-read.table(...)

```
>w
  V1 V2 
1 10 1,000
2  9 2,000
```

because of the comma in 1,000 2,000 and i found

```
>class(V2)
[1]"factor"
>class(V1)
[1]"interger"
```

how could i do in R to convert V2 to interger 1000 2000 directly

not to change the data in .txt

i try

```
>as.numeric(as.character(w))
```

but it not successiful

Comment: Use the `dec` argument of `read.table`, i.e. `read.table(..., dec = ",")`.

Comment: @Pascal Couldn't get it right with `dec=","`  `read.table('file.txt', dec=",")[1:2,2]#
[1] 1,000 2,000`

Comment: @akrun If OP system decimal is ",", then it works.

Comment: i use read.table(...,dec=",") but 2,000 1,000 is change to 2.0,1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can remove the `,` with `gsub` and convert to `numeric` class

```
w$V2 <- as.numeric(gsub(',', '', w$V2))
str(w)
# 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ V1: int  10 9
# $ V2: num  1000 2000
```